# run PMD through java

Tags: java, pmd

I am trying to run PMD through java following this website 
http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3/running.html

when i run this command in the command prompt:

```
java net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD /path/to/source text basic,imports,unusedcode
```

it seems to throw the error:
Error: Could not find or load main class net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD

What is needed to run this command?

Comment: Is your command prompt running from inside the pmd directory?

Comment: Unrelated but of note, PMD 4.3 is **ancient**. You should really look for a newer version. PMD 5.8.1 is the latest as of this writing, but 6.0.0 is really close.

Comment: Sidenote: running PMD by calling `java` with the main class directly is totally possible, provided you have all the jars of PMD's `lib` dir on the classpath (using the `-cp` option or the `CLASSPATH` environment variable). A much simpler way of running PMD is to use the startup scripts provided in the `bin` directory, which take care of loading the jars for you. These are `run.sh pmd` if for Unix/Linux and `pmd.bat` for Windows (see [this page](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.8.1/usage/running.html) for more details)

Answer (score 0):

You need the -cp command line argument and the list of jar files after it.  The paths to the jar file can be absolute, starting with C:\ or /, or relative to your current directory.  Without the -cp listofjars Java cannot find the main class but it is not found on your filesystem relative to the current directory.  It is in one of the jar files.

Edit: on second glance, the command you show is an example template command further down on the page.  It is not meant to be run on its own.  You need to fill in the arguments with real files and options.